# Дочерний div должен зависеть от родительского

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста разобраться в css.

Есть большой `div` с `margin:0` 
Внтури него маленький `div` с `margin:30px;`

Проблема в том что маленький отступает от браузера, а мне надо чтобы он отталкивался от родительского `diva.

В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для маленького padding.

Comment: это помогло, спасибо, но не могли бы объяснить как так...
на сколько я знаю margin - это отступ элемента от внешних объектов,
а padding - это поля для внутренних объектов... тут логичнее было бы  применять padding для большого div'а, но я так делал - никакого эффекта. Так в чем соль ?)

Comment: Да, Вы правы, логичнее в данной ситуации использовать padding для большого div. 
Посмотрите пример, там всё работает:
http://jsfiddle.net/xeSk3/

Answer (score 1):

Нужно задать родительскому большому div и маленькому - position:absolute;
**например:**

```
<div style="position:absolute; margin:0px; width:500px; height:300px;"><div style="position:absolute; margin:90px; width:100px; height:100px;"></div></div>
```

Comment: при таком варианте все блоки смещаются в начала координат (я забыл указать что основной блок margin:0 auto)

Comment: большому - relative ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/xeSk3/2/